# How do I use bash style $() syntax with the posix shell?

Tags: shell, posix

I have this base command:
`SOME_VAR='blabhablhaba' bash -c "$(curl -L https://run_script.sh)"`

How do I do this with the posix shell? This fails:
`SOME_VAR='blabhablhaba' sh -c "$(curl -L https://run_script.sh)"`

```
sh: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you're using the wrong sort of quotes, or the shell script you're downloading is a `bash` script rather than a POSIX `sh` script.

What you have at the moment is that the `curl` is executed with *the current shell*, and the result pasted into the `sh -c "..."` expression ready for execution by `sh`.

Try this, which defers the entire download and execution to `sh`,

```
SOME_VAR='blabhablhaba' sh -c '$(curl -L https://run_script.sh)'
```

(The URL you've included as your example is flawed, in that there's no remote hostname. I'm assuming that's because it's a placeholder example.)

In all cases you should be aware that you are implicitly trusting the remote system not to deliver you a malicious script. Do you also trust their security?

Comment: though note that `sh -c '$(...)'` is quite different from `sh -c "$(...)"`, they'd do the same thing only if the command outputs a simple command with no redirections or such. The first one would need to have an `eval` there to get the same effect as the second. But yeah, I think the issue is that the downloaded script needs Bash and not `sh`.

Comment: Yes `SOME_VAR='blabhablhaba' sh -c '$(curl -L https://run_script.sh)'` where sh does a split+glob on the output of `curl` makes little sense. `SOME_VAR='blabhablhaba' sh -c 'eval "$(curl -L https://run_script.sh)"'` would make more sense but be little different from the OP's original. I think we all agree the problem is likely that `curl` outputs some code that is not in the sh language. I'd bet it uses ksh-style process substitution here like `cmd <(...)`.